# can't see c:\windows\system32\_impact.log, but chrome can open it

Tags: windows-8

I am running Windows 8 x64.

Using a development tool created this log file. Chrome was launched from the dev tool to open it. But I cannot see it from Windows Explorer or Command Prompt. I have show all files / hidden files / system files turned on. It does not appear. I am concerned there may be a root kit. I have disabled UAC (put to bottom)

When the file got updated by the dev tool, I was able to refresh it and see it in chrome. I could also close chrome (fully) and reopen chrome and still see it from there. I just can't find it in the folder view or with the command prompt.

Chrome opens this:
file:///C:/windows/system32/_impact.log

Can someone tell me if this is a likely a root kit, or is there something else going on here?

Thanks,
Nachum

Comment: What happens when you copy that URI and paste it in another browser?

Comment: i found no reference to that filename on the web; can you open it from notepad giving the path or any other editor to check the contents?

Comment: IE couldn't open it... Not sure why. The filename is from the dev tool, there is no malicious meaning to the filename _impact.log. The worry is that a rootkit is somehow hiding all filenames that start with underscore. I doubt there actually is a rootkit, but i don't understand why I can't see the log file.

I can open it in Chrome, but I can't see it in Windows Explorer or with the Command Prompt.

Comment: What dev tool? Try elevating the command prompt, then running dir c:\windows\system32\_impact.log /a-d

Comment: Have you tried searching for the file under C:\Windows from Explorer or the Command Prompt? Have you looked in C:\Windows\SysWOW64?

Comment: Thanks Karan! Never thought to look in SYSWOW64. What craziness! It was right there, visible as day. I can't understand why Chrome opens it with the path for system32. That is really strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karan answered this question. The files were in C:\Windows\SysWow64. Thanks Karan